# Problems in copying resultset to Excel, Access 2003/20007

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007

I've got a Access 2003 application that generates Excel reports by querying Sybase.

One of the reports produces 204,000 rows.
This was getting split across multiple sheets in Excel 2003.

I'm now testing whether Excel 2007 can be used and if all data can be dumped into a single sheet.

The Access VBA code used to copy result sets to Excel:

***workSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs***

It seems to work when the number of rows is around 90,000, but does not work at all for 204,000 rows.

I'm testing this on Windows 2003 server.

I've converted the app to Access 2007 and still face the same issues.

Wondering if someone can help with this ... many thx

--Ag

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Excel 2007 is installed on the machine running the Access app and that you are specifying the FileFormat:=52 in your .SaveAs method.

Comment: Yes, Access 2007 and Excel 2007 have been installed on the same machine.

The Access app opens up a Excel template and populates the data ... so am not sure if specifying the above FileFormat applies to this issue.

Comment: Eventhough you're using a template, make sure if you are saving the file in code, it is not changing the format in the.saveas method.